# MultiBoot USB on mac

Tags: mac, usb

I have recently purchased the SanDisk dual Drive 512 GB from Amazon.

Basically I want my USB to do the following.

have a live system running of the following OSs:

- macOS Catalina
- Windows10 Pro
- Linux Kali
- Linux Ubuntu
- Linux Arch
- Parrot OS

Have the Installers of the Installers of the following OSs:

- macOS Catalina
- Windows10 Pro
- Linux Kali
- Linux Ubuntu
- Linux Arch
- Parrot OS

I am getting into Ethical Hacking and Pen Testing, and I really want to have a USB where I can always have all my Data ready wherever I am. I use macOS so it would be nice if there was a software for this, but I can always just VM into any other Os if there's a Software for that. Thanks for any answers ^^

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to achieve this installation as macOS doesn't support live booting like Linux distros.

You can have an EFI partition containing multiple boot-loaders entries for MAC, Linux and Windows and you must also create other partitions for the live booting and installation media.

Use Grub to boot Linux and Windows and Clover to boot your mac installations.

These are well documented on Youtube and Google.